# ne nice editor syntax highlighting - Perl variables not highlighted

Tags: perl, syntax-highlighting, nicedit

I sometimes need to use the **ne** nice editor on a terminal to modify Perl files.

I can't find a way to get Perl variables (you know, anything starting with **$**, **@** or **%**) to highlight at all.

The syntax definition file is extremely complex and hacking it with my extremely limited understanding of the file syntax gets me nowhere.

Also: I would like to use more colors than the **red/blue/yellow/green/cyan/magenta/white/black**, but did not find a way either to use RGB syntax for that.

NB: my terminal emulator allows for 256 colors.

Any pointers appreciated.

I am pasting below the Perl syntax def file content: I tried to play with various RGB syntaxes (blind, since I'm unable to find a definite spec, or if it is at all possible): #rrggbb, @rrggbb, %rrggbb, etc. That's for the colors part.

As for detecting variables: the file clearly spells out a color for variables ("=Var magenta"). This works for other languages, I could successfully play with variable colors and get variables highlighted.

But on Perl files, zero variable detection takes place, no matter which color is used. There should be a way to enforce that variables start with $/@/%, but I don't even know where to start to specify this...

Def file for Perl below the line. Which is horribly convoluted compared to other languages syntax files, and I guess that's my problem: too complex to hack.

---

```
# JOE syntax highlight file for Perl

# Define colors

=Idle
=Preproc blue
=Comment dim yellow
=POD green
=Constant green
=String green
=Escape bold green
=Type bold
=Keyword bold blue
=Bad bold red
=Var magenta


:begin Idle
        *               begin noeat call=.perl()

#
# Perl as a subroutine for Mason
#

.subr perl

# Detect pod

:idle Idle
        *               idle1           noeat
.ifdef mason_line
        "\n"            idle return
.else
        "\n"            idle
.endif
        "="             pod_start

# allow keywords

:idle1 Idle
        *               idle1
        "#"             line_comment_i  recolor=-1
        "\n"            idle noeat
        "0"             first_digit     recolor=-1
        "1-9"           decimal recolor=-1
        "."             maybe_float
        "\""            string          recolor=-1
        "'"             char            recolor=-1
        "`"             backtick        recolor=-1
        "<"             maybe_inc
        "$"             not_string      buffer
.ifdef mason_block
        "&%"            perl_maybe_done buffer
        "-a-zA-Z_@"     ident           buffer
.else
        "/"             regex           recolor=-1
        "-a-zA-Z_@%&"   ident           buffer
.endif

:perl_maybe_done Idle
        *               ident noeat
        ">"             idle1   recolor=-2 return

# prevent keywords

:rest Idle
        *               rest
        "({;~"          idle1
        "#"             line_comment    recolor=-1
        "\n"            idle noeat
        "0"             first_digit     recolor=-1
        "1-9"           decimal recolor=-1
        "."             maybe_float
        "\""            string          recolor=-1
        "'"             char            recolor=-1
        "`"             backtick        recolor=-1
        "$"             not_string      buffer
        "<"             maybe_inc
.ifdef mason_block
        "&%"            perl_maybe_done buffer
        "a-zA-Z_@"      maybe_string    buffer
.else
        "a-zA-Z_@%&"    maybe_string    buffer
.endif

:pod_start Idle
        *               pod_start
        "\n"            pod_block

:pod_block POD
        *               pod_block
        "="             pod_ident       buffer

:pod_ident POD
        *               pod_block       noeat strings
        "=cut"          rest
done
        "a-zA-Z0-9_"    pod_ident

:maybe_inc Idle
        *               rest            noeat
.ifdef mason_block
        "/"             perl_maybe_done_2
.endif
        "<"             maybe_inc1

:perl_maybe_done_2 Idle
        *               perl_idle       noeat
        "a-z"           perl_maybe_done_2
        ">"             idle


:maybe_inc1 Idle
        *               rest            noeat
        "       "       maybe_inc1
        "'\""           quoted_inc_start        save_c recolor=-1
        "A-Za-z_"       inc             buffer noeat

:quoted_inc_start Var
        *               quoted_inc      buffer

:quoted_inc Var
        *               quoted_inc
        &               skipline        save_s

:inc Var
        *               skipline        save_s noeat
        "A-Za-z0-9_"    inc

# Should be treated as a normal line here...

:skipline Idle
        *               skipline
        "\n"            next_line

:todelim Constant
        *               todelim
        "\n"            next_line       strings
        "&"             founddelim
done

# eat \n so it's not in string.
:next_line Constant
        *               todelim         buffer
        "\n"            next_line

:founddelim Var
        *               idle            noeat

:regex Constant
        *               regex
        "\\"            regex_quote     recolor=-1
        "/"             rest

:regex_quote Escape
        *               regex

:not_string Idle
        *               rest noeat
        "A-Za-z_"       ident
        "\"'`#"         rest

:line_comment Comment
        *               line_comment
        "\n"            rest

:line_comment_i Comment
        *               line_comment_i
        "\n"            idle noeat

:end_of_file_comment Comment
        *               end_of_file_comment

:first_digit Constant
        *               rest    noeat
        "x"             hex
        "b"             binary
        "b"             binary
        "."             float
        "eE"            epart
        "0-7"           octal
        "89"            bad_number      recolor=-1

:bad_number Bad
        *               rest    noeat
        "0-9"           bad_number

:octal Constant
        *               rest    noeat
        "0-7_"          octal
        "89"            bad_number      recolor=-1

:binary Constant
        *               rest    noeat
        "01_"           binary
        "2-9"           bad_number      recolor=-1

:hex Constant
        *               rest    noeat
        "0-9A-Fa-f_"    hex

:decimal Constant
        *               rest    noeat
        "0-9_"          decimal
        "eE"            epart
        "."             float

:maybe_float Constant
        *               rest    recolor=-2      noeat
        "0-9"           float           recolor=-2

:float Constant
        *               rest    noeat
        "eE"            epart
        "0-9_"          float

:epart Constant
        *               rest    noeat
        "0-9+\-"        enum

:enum Constant
        *               rest    noeat
        "0-9_"          enum

:string Constant
        *               string
        "\""            rest
        "\\"            string_escape   recolor=-1
        "$@"            string_subst    recolor=-1

:string_subst Escape
        *               string  noeat recolor=-1
        "a-zA-Z_0-9"    string_subst

:string_escape Escape
        *               string
        "x"             string_hex1
        "c"             string_ctrl
        "N"             string_named
        "0-7"           string_octal2
        "\n"            string          recolor=-2

:string_named Escape
        *               string
        "{"             string_named_rest

:string_named_rest Escape
        *               string_named_rest
        "}"             string

:string_ctrl Escape
        *               string

:string_hex1 Escape
        *               string          noeat
        "{"             string_unicode
        "0-9a-fA-F"     string_hex2

:string_unicode Escape
        *               string_unicode
        "}"             string

:string_hex2 Escape
        *               string          noeat
        "0-9a-fA-F"     string

:string_octal2 Escape
        *               string          noeat
        "0-7"           string_octal3

:string_octal3 Escape
        *               string          noeat
        "0-7"           string

:char Constant
        *               char
#       "\n"            idle noeat
        "'"             rest
        "\\"            char_escape     recolor=-1

:char_escape    Escape
        *               char            recolor=-2
        "\\'"   char

:backtick       Constant
        *               backtick
        "`"             rest
        "\\"            backtick_escape recolor=-1
        "$@"            backtick_subst recolor=-1

:backtick_subst Escape
        *               backtick        noeat recolor=-1
        "a-zA-Z_0-9"    backtick_subst

:backtick_escape Escape
        *               backtick
        "x"             backtick_hex1
        "c"             backtick_ctrl
        "N"             backtick_named
        "0-7"           backtick_octal2
        "\n"            backtick                recolor=-2

:backtick_named Escape
        *               backtick
        "{"             backtick_named_rest

:backtick_named_rest Escape
        *               backtick_named_rest
        "}"             backtick


:backtick_ctrl Escape
        *               backtick

:backtick_hex1 Escape
        *               backtick                noeat
        "{"             backtick_unicode
        "0-9a-fA-F"     backtick_hex2

:backtick_unicode Escape
        *               backtick_unicode
        "}"             backtick

:backtick_hex2 Escape
        *               backtick                noeat
        "0-9a-fA-F"     backtick

:backtick_octal2 Escape
        *               backtick                noeat
        "0-7"           backtick_octal3

:backtick_octal3 Escape
        *               backtick                noeat
        "0-7"           backtick

:ident  Idle
        *               rest            noeat strings
        "BEGIN"         kw
        "END"           kw
        "if"            kw
        "unless"        kw
        "while"         kw
        "until"         kw
        "foreach"       kw
        "sub"           kw
        "my"            kw
        "our"           kw
        "do"            kw
        "if"            kw
        "else"          kw
        "elsif"         kw
        "for"           kw
        "continue"      kw
        "last"          kw
        "print"         kw
        "reset"         kw
        "die"           kw
        "goto"          kw
        "require"       kw
        "use"           kw
        "eval"          kw
        "redo"          kw
        "next"          kw
        "warn"          kw
        "return"        kw
        "printf"        kw
        "close"         kw
        "package"       kw
        "m"             match
        "qr"            match
        "qq"            match
        "qx"            match
        "qw"            match
        "q"             match
        "s"             subst
        "tr"            subst
        "y"             subst
        "__END__"       end_of_file_comment
        "__DATA__"      end_of_file_comment
done
        "a-zA-Z0-9_"    ident

:maybe_string Idle
        *               rest            noeat strings
        "qr"            match
        "qq"            match
        "qx"            match
        "qw"            match
        "q"             match
done
        "a-zA-Z0-9_"    maybe_string

:type Type
        *       rest    noeat

:kw Keyword
        *       rest    noeat

:match Idle
        *               inmatch         save_c recolor=-1
        "       "       match

:inmatch Constant
        *               inmatch
        &               rest
        "\\"            inmatch_quote   recolor=-1

:inmatch_quote Escape
        *               inmatch

:subst Idle
        *               insubst         save_c recolor=-1
        "<([{`"         delim_insubst   save_c recolor=-1
        "       "       subst

:insubst Constant
        *               insubst
        &               inrepl
        "\\"            insubst_quote   recolor=-1

:insubst_quote Escape
        *               insubst

:inrepl Constant
        *               inrepl
        &               rest
        "\\"            inrepl_quote

:inrepl_quote Escape
        *               inrepl

:delim_insubst Constant
        *               delim_insubst
        &               delim_repl
        "\\"            delim_quote

:delim_quote Escape
        *               delim_insubst

:delim_repl Constant
        *               repl            save_c recolor=-1
        "       "       delim_repl

 L:      441 C:        1  97%  i-----pvurT------@A perl.jsf                                                                            
        *               inmatch

:subst Idle
        *               insubst         save_c recolor=-1
        "<([{`"         delim_insubst   save_c recolor=-1
        "       "       subst

:insubst Constant
        *               insubst
        &               inrepl
        "\\"            insubst_quote   recolor=-1

:insubst_quote Escape
        *               insubst

:inrepl Constant
        *               inrepl
        &               rest
        "\\"            inrepl_quote

:inrepl_quote Escape
        *               inrepl

:delim_insubst Constant
        *               delim_insubst
        &               delim_repl
        "\\"            delim_quote

:delim_quote Escape
        *               delim_insubst

:delim_repl Constant
        *               repl            save_c recolor=-1
        "       "       delim_repl

:repl Constant
        *               repl
        &               rest
        "\\"            repl_quote

:repl_quote Escape
        *               repl

.end
```

Comment: knb is saying your question might be more appropriate for https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/, though I don't agree. You are asking for help editing `ne`'s syntax definition file (which is on topic), not looking for an editor recommendation (which isn't). Now, I don't know `ne`, but it seems to me that you should show what you've attempted so far, or at least the relevant part of the existing file.

Comment: `ne` uses syntax highlighting from [`joe`](https://joe-editor.sourceforge.io/). Searching based on that should give you some leads.

Comment: @nega: indeed I rapidly came to looking at Joe's help pages and user comments. Before coming here to ask for help !

Comment: @knb I edited the question to ask more details (including the file itself, to show the extent of the mess).

Comment: [`joe`'s manual](https://joe-editor.sourceforge.io/4.6/man.html#how-joe-syntax-highlighting-works) isn't great on the subject. Have you looked at `joe`'s [_c.jsf_](http://joe-editor.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/joe-editor/joe-editor/file/tip/syntax/c.jsf.in). It seems to have a fairly complete description. Look especially at lines 181-188.